# I need help with plant identification

Tags: identification, flowers

This plant has fuzzy, oblong leaves with a center fold. The flowers are about 2 inches long, white, tubular with petals on the ends and are on tall reddish stems. The plant blooms in summer and was originally from Arizona.[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is a nice plant with typical flowers and is called hardy white gloxinia (*Sinningia tubiflora*). It has tubers, and can handle short periods of frost in winter. It is related to African violets and cape primrose ([ref.](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/growing-habits-sinningia-tubiflora-21836.html)).